# Cloud functions/Firestore. How to trigger when the fields stay in different documents

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, promise, google-cloud-functions

[image]

**As pictured above**, I have two documents in my device-configs collection. The first: device-configs/garagem. Which I'll call document_1. And the second: device-configs/garagem2. Which I'll call document_2.

Whenever the field garagestate (document_2) is false, the value of the field (**type map)** value.openPercent of document_1 must be 100. Whenever the field garagestate (document_2) is true, the value of the field value.openPercent of document_1 must be 0 **Explaining**: There is a possibility within the project of the value of document_2 to be changed manually in other Client project. So I need this cloud functions trigger/onUpdate.

**Below I present the code I currently have and the issue. Every help is welcome:**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { firestore } = require("./admin");

exports.updateGarage = functions.firestore
  .document("device-configs/garagem2")
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    // Get an object representing the document
    // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
    const newValue = change.after.data();

    const garagestatev = newValue.garagestate;

      firestore
      .doc(`device-configs/garagem`)
      .get()
      .then((areaSnapshot) => {

        const targetDoc = areaSnapshot.data().value.openPercent

            if (garagestatev) {
                console.log("garagestate is true = targetDodc=k"+targetDoc);
      
                if (targetDoc == 100) {
                  console.log("vou mandar 0");
      
                  firestore
                    .collection("device-confings")
                    .document("garagem")
                    .update(mapOf("value.openPercent", to, 0));
                }

            } else if (!garagestatev) {
                
                console.log("garagestate is false = targetDodc=k"+targetDoc);

                if (targetDoc == 0) {
                  console.log("vou mandar 100");
                  firestore
                    .collection("device-confings")
                    .document("garagem")
                    .update(mapOf("value.openPercent", to, 100));
                }
              }
      });
  });


firebase functions:log --project control-my-lighs
2021-05-30T18:04:14.031Z ? updateGarage:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2021-05-30T18:04:15.107Z E updateGarage: Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:275:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)
2021-05-30T18:04:25.644468172Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T18:14:28.870453Z I : 
2021-05-30T18:14:29.170182Z I : 
2021-05-30T18:14:30.371944Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T18:15:36.776727Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T18:28:51.856151587Z D updateGarage: Function execution started
2021-05-30T18:28:51.911Z W updateGarage: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
2021-05-30T18:28:51.925301683Z D updateGarage: Function execution took 70 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2021-05-30T18:32:16.601Z ? updateGarage: Unhandled rejection
2021-05-30T18:32:16.601Z ? updateGarage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined
2021-05-30T18:32:16.601Z ? updateGarage:     at /workspace/index.js:20:9
2021-05-30T18:32:16.601Z ? updateGarage:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2021-05-30T18:32:17.970Z E updateGarage: Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:275:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)
2021-05-30T18:41:52.632854Z I : 
2021-05-30T18:41:52.986410Z I : 
2021-05-30T18:41:54.241235Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T18:43:05.140969Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T19:25:19.353311Z I : 
2021-05-30T19:25:19.700197Z I : 
2021-05-30T19:25:20.976786Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T19:26:25.017448Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T19:28:08.685592Z I : 
2021-05-30T19:28:08.950658Z I : 
2021-05-30T19:28:10.193327Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T19:29:11.637770Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T19:34:04.532315Z I : 
2021-05-30T19:34:04.876667Z I : 
2021-05-30T19:34:06.052541Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T19:35:13.534912Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T19:35:43.595986Z I : 
2021-05-30T19:35:43.852178Z I : 
2021-05-30T19:35:45.180154Z N updateGarage: 
2021-05-30T19:36:55.044093Z N updateGarage:
```

https://github.com/neuberfran/updateGarage/blob/main/functions/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Cloud Function should return a Promise or a value. In your case, you should return the Promise which gets the value from the database, and then subsequently updates the other document.

Also, you should not nest Promises. It is recommended to use [Promise Chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

**UPDATE:**
I have added the code after adding Promise chaining and returning the promise in the cloud function. `mapOf` is also not required as you can update the object directly.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
    exports.updateGarage = functions.firestore
        .document("device-configs/garagem2")
        .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    
            //Get the latest value after update
            const newValue = change.after.data();
    
            //Current state of garage
            const garagestatev = newValue.garagestate;
    
            return admin.firestore().doc(`device-configs/garagem`).get()
                .then((areaSnapshot) => areaSnapshot.data().value.openPercent)
                .then(targetDoc => {
    
                    //Target doc has openPercent of other document ('garagem')
                    if (garagestatev) {
                        console.log("garagestate is true = targetDodc=k" + targetDoc);
    
                        if (targetDoc === 100) {
                            console.log("vou mandar 0");
                            //Returning Promise inside of .then() block 
                            return admin.firestore()
                                .collection("device-configs")
                                .doc("garagem")
                                .update({ "value.openPercent": 0 });
                        }
    
                    } else {
    
                        console.log("garagestate is false = targetDodc=k" + targetDoc);
    
                        if (targetDoc === 0) {
                            console.log("vou mandar 100");
                            //Returning Promise inside of .then() block 
                            return admin.firestore()
                                .collection("device-configs")
                                .doc("garagem")
                                .update({ "value.openPercent": 100 });
                        }
                    }
                })
    
        });
```

You can also add checks for whether the document exists or not if that's not guaranteed.

Comment: What would I need to change in my code (above) specifically?

Comment: I have edited the answer with a code snippet.

Comment: Tks. But not solved Yet. The function compiles and appears ok on the console. But I still have the following issue: updateGarage: TypeError: firestore.collection(...).document is not a function    https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/468f836de252cf57755b95dffb9da17d#file-firebase-functions-log-project-control-my-lighs        https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NoB2lGs18iT3iyqfZd929Vv51Uq7_aq5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: replace (2x) device-confings with device-configs (Correct) in your answer. But the issue: TypeError: firestore.collection(...).document is not a function Continues

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't check the imports. I have edited the answer to reflect the imports (`admin.firestore()`) needs to be called as a function. You also have to initialize the app using `admin.initializeApp();`. Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it still hasn't solved: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ZHw9Y6l4pbrB1wxi7ogmaj5tEjMBhR6/view?usp=sharing

Regarding the inclusion of this line: admin.initializeApp(); We must not forget that I have the following file in the project: https://github.com/neuberfran/updateGarage/blob/main/functions/admin.js

Comment: Sorry my bad! The function call should be `admin.firestore().collection("...").doc("...")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233147/discussion-between-nikhil-kothari-and-neuber-sousa).